# Como hacer select con inner join Ruby console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Necesito realizar un select con un inner join a otra tabla desde la consola de ruby, las tablas que tengo son las siguientes:

```
calendars:
    calendar_id
    provider_id
    validity_start
    validity_end
    duration_turn
    schedule_id

schedules:
    schedule_id
    day
    hs_start
    hs_end
```

Lo que necesito es hacer un select inner join para que me traiga estos datos:

```
calendars.duration_turn 
schedules.hs_start
```

Con la siguiente condicion:

```
provider_id='9920' AND schedules.day='5' AND 
(calendars.validity_start<'29.01.2020') AND 
(calendars.validity_end>'29.01.2020')
```

He probado con la siguiente linea pero no me trae todos los datos que solicito, solo me trae `schedules.hs_start`:

```
Schedule.find_by_sql("SELECT calendars.duration_turn, schedules.hs_start FROM
calendars INNER JOIN schedules ON calendars.schedule_id=schedules.id 
WHERE provider_id='9920' AND schedules.day='5' AND 
(calendars.validity_start<'29.01.2020') AND 
(calendars.validity_end>'29.01.2020')")
```

Y si cambio Schedule por Calendar me trae solo calendars.duration_turn:

```
Calendar.find_by_sql("SELECT calendars.duration_turn, schedules.hs_start FROM 
calendars INNER JOIN schedules ON calendars.schedule_id=schedules.id WHERE
provider_id='9920' AND schedules.day='5' AND
(calendars.validity_start<'29.01.2020') AND
(calendars.validity_end>'29.01.2020')")
```

Comment: Lo he podido solucionar con la siguiente linea:
Calendar.joins(:schedule).where("provider_id='9920' AND schedules.day='5'")

Comment: Si has encontrado una solución, agrégala como respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he podido solucionar con la siguiente linea:

```
Calendar.joins(:schedule).where("provider_id='9920' AND schedules.day='5'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola el problema que tienes que esos join solo traen los datos del primer modelo en este caso calendar puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
Calendar.select("calendars.duration_turn,schedules.hs_start)
.joins("INNER JOIN schedules ON calendars.schedule_id=schedules.id")
.where("provider_id='9920' AND schedules.day='5' AND 
calendars.validity_start<'29.01.2020' AND 
calendars.validity_end>'29.01.2020'")
```

Comment: Aqui debajo poublique la respuesta, para traer algo de la tabla schedules solo basta con llamarlo de la siguiente manera: calendar.schedule.hs_start